# how to handle incorrect values inserted from source code?

Tags: php, laravel

There is a page where the user select the quantities that he wants for each ticket type, then the user click in next and he goes to a page that shows a summary of the request.

In this page where user select the quantities, for each ticket type there is a minimum and maximum quantities that the user can select, for example for the ticket type "center bench" the user can select a maximum is of tickets and for the ticket type "lateral bench" a maximum of 3.

**Do you know how correct this issue**: if the user in this selected quantities page, change the quantity in source code to for example to "1000000" for the ticket type "center bench" and click "Next" the dd($request->all()); shows:

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => ""
  "type" => array:2 [▼
    "center bench" => "1000000"
    "lateral bench" => "1"
  ]
```

So the controller will receive "center bench" => "100000", and this is incorrect.

Do you know how to handle this?

**Code:**

So in the first page there is this code for the user select the quantities for each ticket type:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <li>
            <span>{{$ticket->title}}</span> 
            <form method="post" action="{{route('congress.registration', ['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">

                <select name=type[{{ $ticket->title }}]>
                    <option selected>0</option>
                    ...
                </select>
            </form>
            <span>X {{$ticket->showPrice()}}</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
        <span>0.00€</span>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
    </form>
</ul>
```

When "Next" button Im getting the selected quantities for the user in a array and return to the registration page using the storeQuantity() method:

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function storeTypes(Request $request){
         dd($request->all());
        $selectedTypes = $request->type;
        return view('congresses.registration')->with('selectedTypes', $selectedTtypes);
    }
}
```

Comment: add a JavaScript validator in your Blade template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could control the value the user can put in the form with a javascript validator (like [parsleyjs](http://parsleyjs.org/)), but you **must** validate the data on the backend always, we **never**, ever, **trust the user**.

That's why Laravel have a really good way to validate incoming data in your controller, you can find there how to [validate the application's incoming data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation).

Looking that, you can do something like:

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function storeTypes(Request $request){
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
           'type.center bench' => 'required|max:100',
           //add there more validation rules...
        ]);

        $selectedTypes = $request->type;
        return view('congresses.registration')->with('selectedTypes', $selectedTtypes);
    }
}
```

If the validation fails it will redirect back  to the view with an MessageBag object which contains all the validation errors.